# indexed family of sets, not pairwise disjoint but whole family is disjoint

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've seen this problem before, but can't remember how to finish it:

Define an indexed family of sets $ \{A_i : i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ in which for any $m,n\in \mathbb{N}, A_m \cap A_n \not= \emptyset$ and $\bigcap A_i = \emptyset$. The closest I came was something to the effect of $A_i = \{(0, 1/n): n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, but I know that doesn't meet the last criterion.

Suggestions on how to fix/finish it? Am I even as close as I think I am?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you are done.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't meet the last criterion? It does.

Comment: Cool--I guess I thought there would always be an overlap at the end; is that eliminated because there's always a smaller interval than any nth interval?

Comment: You may go like this: Suppose $a>0$ is a member of the infinite intersection. Then, find an index $n$ such that $a\notin A_n$ (choosing $n$ such that $a > \frac{1}{n}$ works) that leads to a contradiction. The fact that $0$ is not a member of the intersection is obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Further to Hagen von Eitzen and Asaf Karagila's answers, you could set
$$A_1=\{0,1\}, \quad A_2 = \{ 0,2 \}, \quad A_n=\{1,2\}\ \text{for}\ n \ge 3$$
No need for any clever reasoning about infinite sets.

Answer (score 3):

There are several obvious ways to do this, and some less obvious ways too:

- $A_n=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid n<x\}$;
- $A_n=\left(0,\frac1n\right)$;
- $A_n=\Bbb N\setminus\{n\}$;
- $A_n=\{k\in\Bbb N\mid k\text{ is positive and divisible by the }n\text{-th prime number}\}$;
- $A_n=\{n\cdot k\mid k\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}\}$ for $n>0$, and $A_0=\Bbb N$ (if $x\in A_n$ for all $n$ then $x$ can be divided by every number, which is impossible).

There are many more ways which are interesting and can reflect on many mathematical properties related to finiteness and countability.

Answer (score 2):

How about $A_i =\{n\in\mathbb N\mid n>i\}$? But your choice, more properly written $A_i=(0,1/i)$,  is also fine.

Comment: Great--thanks so much!